# Find single parent id containing exactly two given children

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, relational-division

I have a thread table whose id is foreign key column to thread_members table as thread_id.

Thread to thread_members has one to many relation.

If thread members given are 5 and 55, I have to find thread which contains only 5 and 55 but there can be many threads containing 5,55 and other members but only one having 5 and 55.

How can i achieve this in MySQL.

Comment: Let us see what you have tried please

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RiggsFolly select thread from thread_members where user_id in(5,55)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT thread_id
FROM thread_members
GROUP BY thread_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN user_id IN (5, 55) THEN 1 END) = 2
```

The above returns threads that contain exactly two members, 5 and 55. It assumes that your data does not contain duplicate `thread_id, user_id` pairs.